# Proper use of command pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I have the following scenario.

I want to be able to send notifications when something bad happens in my application.  There are 2 types of notifications that should be available.
1.) Email Notification
2.) Event log Notification

Unfortunately, both of these types of notifications require some "Uncommon" information in order to be useful ( Emails need email address, SMTP Addresses...etc while Eventlogs would never need that information. )

I was thinking of using the CommandPattern to encapsulate and hide these details from my Application Service that sends notifications.  Therefore, THe notification service only has a list of commands.  When a notification needs to be sent, it simply iterates through it's list of commands and executes them.  Is this a viable solution in order to decouple my application service from specific implementations of Notification implementations?

Example of Notification Service

```
public class NotificationService
{
     IList<ICommand> _notificationCommands;
     void SendNotifications()
     {
         foreach ( vat notification in _notificationCommands)
                 notification.Execute();
     }
}
```

Is this the proper solution/use of the command pattern?

Comment: You will have to pass the information it needs in the concrete class of each command and so it can be different for each concrete class.

Comment: i know that :)! My question is simply am i using the pattern for the right reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Command pattern might work. However, I would consider an EventAggregator approach where you emit typed events. A much more appropriate solution, IMHO.

http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/06/29/build-your-own-cab-11-event-aggregator/
http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html